# Route [language.set] not defined

Tags: laravel

I know I'm bad at explaining what's wrong with codes, but I'm really trying to make everyone understand.
If, for example, there was a Swedish site where you could ask, things would go much better.

I have just solved many problems with this installation, but it is a bug that I do not understand and that I do not get rid of.

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [language.set] not defined. (View: \views\layouts\partials\header.blade.php)

Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::route
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:420
```

This is my code:

```
public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)

    {

        if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {

            return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);

        }

 

        throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");

    }
```

UPPDATE:

Thanks for the answer, in my web.php i only have

```
<?php
```

in header.blade.php i find this code:

```
<div class="header-language">

                                @php 
                                $get_data = App\Category::where([
                                    ['type','lang'],
                                    ['status',1]
                                ])->get();
                                @endphp
                                <input type="hidden" id="lang_url" value="{{ route('language.set') }}">
                                <select id="select_language" name="language">
                                    @foreach($get_data as $key=>$data)
                                    @php
                                        $info = json_decode($data->content);
                                    @endphp
                                    <option {{ Session::get('locale') == $data->slug ? 'selected' : ''  }} value="{{ $data->slug }}">{{ $info->lang_name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

UPPDATE:
I manage to fix the language.set problem,
i run php artisan route:list

And now i get this problem.

```
Error

  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found

  at \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController.php:38
    34|      * @return void
    35|      */
    36|     public function __construct()
    37|     {
  > 38|         if (Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role->id == 1) {
    39|             $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
    40|         } else {
    41|             $this->redirectTo = route('author.dashboard');
    42|         }

  1   [internal]:0
      App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController::__construct()

  2   \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:849
      ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs([])
```

Confirmpasswordcontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ConfirmsPasswords;

class ConfirmPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Confirm Password Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password confirmations and
    | uses a simple trait to include the behavior. You're free to explore
    | this trait and override any functions that require customization.
    |
    */

    use ConfirmsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users when the intended url fails.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role->id == 1) {
            $this->redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
        } else {
            $this->redirectTo = route('author.dashboard');
        }
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `views\layouts\partials\header.blade.php` you will have called `route('language.set')`. You are getting this error because you don't have a route named "language.set" in your `routes/web.php`. Hope that helps? I would suggest you provide your `routes/web.php` file in your question if not.

Comment: You need to define some routes in `web.php`. Take a look at the [Laravel Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing)

Comment: are they not installed by them self.

Comment: they are defined by default, if they are present in one of the route files :) can you include those? or else you need to tell us what packages you use etc.

Comment: Can you include the use statements of ConfirmPasswordController? a shot in the dark adding: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; to the confirmpasswordcontroller would help